# js Jquery .text() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

i've got this js-code:

```
    $(".dpst_item").click(function(){
            var dpst_id = this.id;
            var text = $('img.'+dpst_id+' span.dpst_item_span').text();
            alert(text);
    }):
```

And this php-code:

```
echo '<div class="dpst_item_div"><img id="' . $item_classid . '" class="dpst_item" class="dpst_item-select" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/' . $item_classid . '/102fx102f" title="' . $item_name . '" ><span id="' . $item_classid . '_price" class="dpst_item_span" style="cursor:pointer">'.$item_price.'$</span></div>';
```

But i dont get anything at alterted.

Comment: There is a space betn the `.` and concatenated `classname` ->`img.'+dpst_id`. Debug using your console.

Comment: Does `.dpst_item` element have an `id`? Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: added the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the span element next to the clicked img tag then you can use **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next)** method to get it.

```
$(".dpst_item").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).next().text();
    alert(text);
}):
```

Comment: Works perfectly! :D

Comment: @VeloFX : glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 `class` attributes which is invalid and browser will ignore one

```
class="dpst_item" class="dpst_item-select"
```

needs to be

```
class="dpst_item dpst_item-select"
```

Also a span can not be a child of an image as suggested by the selector who's text you are looking for